# Combining mysql columns to get nested json result

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a sql table like this:

```
id  a  b  c1  c2  c3  d
 1  x  y  z1  z2  z3  w
 ....
```

I want the following json output

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1",
    "a": "x",
    "b": "y",
    "c": {
        "c1": "z1",
        "c2": "z2",
        "c3": "z4"
        },
    "d": "w"
    }
}
```

How should the mysqli query be for this case? What should be the array format and looping be to convert the query result into the required json?

For a new row, it would be added to data. So it would become "data": {data_of_row1, data_of_row2}

Comment: I have tried a few things but they were no where near the expected output.

Comment: what about if you have more than one row into the table? how the JSON should looks like?

Comment: @mitkosoft: I have added the added how the json should look for multiple rows

Comment: What's wrong with json_encode?

Comment: @Strawberry, I want the sql query and looping to get an array which on json_encode would give the following result

Comment: Also, note that enumerated columns are often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @Strawberry, I know. I numbered them such for ease of understanding

Comment: In which case the best answer below is based upon a mistaken assumption.

Comment: I can add a prefix to the columns which is the basis for grouping the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `preg_match` with `foreach` can do that:

```
    <?php
        $link = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db') or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sql_table ORDER BY id";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $json = array();
        $rc = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            foreach($row as $rowName => $rowValue){
                if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $rowName) !== 0){
                    $index = substr($rowName, 0,1);
                    $json[$rc]['data'][$index][$rowName] = $rowValue;
                }else{
                    $json[$rc]['data'][$rowName] = $rowValue;
                }
            }
            $rc++;
        }
        print_r(json_encode($json));
    ?>
```

Output:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "a": "x",
        "b": "y",
        "c": {
            "c1": "z1",
            "c2": "z2",
            "c3": "z3"
        },
        "d": "w"
    }
}, {
    "data": {
        "id": "2",
        "a": "xx",
        "b": "yy",
        "c": {
            "c1": "zz1",
            "c2": "zz2",
            "c3": "zz3"
        },
        "d": "ww"
    }
}]
```

This will work with any columns similar to yours (`f4, f5, r, t` etc).

Comment: This looks more like it

Comment: Does that code need to be expanded if the data are more deeply nested? Is there a generic version?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica, most probably it should be expanded, as it depends on the name of the table's columns. So we might need an example of how your data is nested and what you want as output, best in a new SO post.

Comment: For the time being, I am examining MySql v8's new JSON functionality. E.g https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `CONCAT` and `explode();`

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, a, b, CONCAT(c1, "|", c2, "|", c3) AS c, d FROM mytable WHERE id = 1");
$rows = $q->fetchAll();

$data = [];

foreach($rows as $row){
    $explC = explode("|", $row['c']);

    $cValues = [];
    foreach($explC as $key => $c){
       $cValues["c".($key+1)] = $c;
    } 

    $data['data'][] = [
      "id" => $row['id'],
      "c" => $cValues
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?